# How to avoid optimistic lock exception

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, optimistic-locking

I am trying to mock the webservice call,and developed a sample client which forms a dummy request and gets response
now what i do is i implement callable in this client class and put all my business logic in call and request formation in constructor.

from another class i created X number of client objects and store them in a list and using Executor Service i am trying to execute this list using invokeALL

when threadpool count in executor is 10 and and my x is 10 working fine
but when i try to increase x to 20 or above i am getting optimistic lock exception

is there a way to solve this problem

Comment: Yes peter this is in JAVA

Comment: The stacktrace would be helpful